# Hive: join tables with array without LATERAL VIEW explode

Tags: sql, arrays, hive, hiveql

I have searched the way to join tables with array coumn on hive, but all answers suggest to use LATERAL view EXPLODE.

I want to get the data like below ;

```
+---------+----------+----------+
|  name   | type_id  | spend_sum|
+---------+----------+----------+
| john    |  9       |   100    | 
+---------+----------+----------+
| ben     |  9       |   350    |
+---------+----------+----------+
| ben     |  8       |   350    |
+---------+----------+----------+
```

From 2 tables below;

Table1

```
+----------+---------------+-----------------+---------+----------+
| order_id | value(array)  |  item_id(array) | name    | spend    |
+----------+---------------+-----------------+---------+----------+
| 1        | [1]           |   [11]          | john    | 100      |
+----------+---------------+-----------------+---------+----------+
| 2        | [2,3]         |  [12,13]        | ben     | 200      |
+----------+---------------+-----------------+---------+----------+
| 3        | [1,2]         |  [11,12]        | ben     | 150      |
+----------+---------------+-----------------+---------+----------+
```

Table2

```
+---------+------------------+---------------+
|  value  | item_id(bigint)  |  type_id(int) |
+---------+------------------+---------------+
| 1       |  11              |    9          | 
+---------+------------------+---------------+
| 2       |  12              |    8          |
+---------+------------------+---------------+
| 3       |  13              |    9          |
+---------+------------------+---------------+
```

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can join using `array_contains(Array<T>, value)` but in Hive non-equality joins are not allowed. So you can do a cross join (or join without ON condition, which is the same) and filter rows multiplied by CROSS JOIN using

`WHERE array_contains(t1.value, t2.value)`

`array_contains()` is a Boolean function, so you can use it in the WHERE clause without additional conditions.

But depending on your tables size, solution with explode+join on exploded values may perform better, because cross join multiplies all rows from one table by all rows from the second one.